# How to really exit a cordova application?

Tags: android, cordova

I put this code in a cordova (3.4.0) app:

```
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="true" />
<preference name="keepRunning" value="false" />
```

but when I push my home button for quit, and push it again, I can see the app keep running in the list ! so, what is the good param?

Comment: What ? When i reopen my app, it's on the last page, she has not been closed. I have a script added at the start of the app, i need app go to sleep. And if this list is not a list of running apps, what is this list ? Are you joking ? If it's a "normal behavior", why this params exists ?

Comment: "And if this list is not a list of running apps, what is this list ?" -- it is called the recent-tasks list. Tasks that appear in that list do not necessarily have running processes associated with them. "Are you joking ?" -- no. Feel free to learn the operating systems for which you are developing apps. While cross-platform tools like Cordova make it easier for you to write apps for many platforms, you still need to know the platforms and how they work.

Comment: "I have a script added at the start of the app, i need app go to sleep" -- no, presumably you need to change your app to run that script at other times. There are many ways the user can switch to another app (HOME, recent-tasks list, notification, incoming phone call), and none of them will necessarily terminate your process.

Comment: "the recent-tasks list" -> and why i see ram and cpu ? so the app is closed you said, she is always on ram and eat cpu, but she is closed. ok. very weird platform !

Comment: i want change a content in a same file, i don't read a good solution in SO, so maybe i can ask question. And for the existence of this params in cordova, finally, they do nothing ?

Comment: App listed here are "not necessarily have running processes associated with them": http://www.oneclickroot.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/android-background-apps-371x660.jpg ?